# ASP.NET Core (3.0) Rangeprocessing Videostream

Tags: asp.net-core, video-streaming

I'm currently expiring an issue. I try to serve a video file via `FileStreamResult`. Basically my code looks like that:

```
public IActionResult Video([FromQuery] int fileId)
    {

        var sfs = _sourceService.GetStreamByFileId(fileId);

        return new FileStreamResult(sfs,new MediaTypeHeaderValue("video/mp4")) {EnableRangeProcessing = true};
    }
```

In the next step I try to present the video on a website. For this example, I've tried the basic HTML5 Video Player.

```
<video controls width="640" height="264">
<source src="UrlToVideoAction" type="video/mp4">
```

Everything works fine. **But if I now try to skip to a later position which isn't buffered at the time, the video player stops buffering/seeking**. My Application doesn't throw any exception.

Then I tried to analyse the requests and responses. I noticed that my browser sends the following range header property when I skip to a specific position which isn't buffered:
`Range: bytes=101318656-`
It seems like the browser tries to fetch the whole ressource. The video player stops playing and if I retry to skip to a new position no further request will be sent. I've tested that behaivour with Firefox, Chrome and Edge. My tested file is about 250 mb. I also tested several other files all in MP4 format (x264, aac)

So my approach basically is to serve a video file in ASP.NET Core which should be able to skip to a specific position.

Thanks for any help.